# Confused about how python _for_ function works

Tags: python

I have a question about how the python function *for* works. I have a program I am writing which involved generating the prime factorization of several numbers.

```
for a in range(2,25):
    print primefactorize(a)
```

When I tested it in the range above, the last list to pop up in the terminal was the prime factorization output for 24, not 25. Does the function

```
for a in range(1,x):
```

only run through each value up to x-1?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget that you can type `help(range)` at the console.  You can also use quotes -- e.g. `help("for")` -- when you want to see help on a keyword.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your confusion is with [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

```
range(2,25)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

From the documentation:

> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic
>   progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must
>   be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1.
>   If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form
>   returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 *
>   step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start
>   + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero
>   (or else ValueError is raised). Example:

In math this is called an [`start` inclusive, `stop` exclusive interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_%28mathematics%29#Intervals) and looks like this:

```
[start, stop)
```

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. I have another question, though. Is there a way to edit the range function I wrote so that it does go to 25 without changing the number? Much appreciated.

Comment: @KevinBradner: If you want a fully-inclusive interval, you can easily write your own function for that: `def inclusive_range(start, stop): return range(start, stop+1)`. Then, you can use `inclusive_range(2, 25)` to get what you want.